# Having an array of Objects as a props for a React component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a parent component named `UsersTable`(it's a chile of some other component and has `users` and `roles`as its props). The `getRoles()` function is getting all the roles for a user using an ajax request. The result is returned to `render()` and stores in `allroles`variable. `allroles`is an array of Objects(`[Object, Object, Object]`) and is sent to the child component, `UserRow`, as its props. But I'm getting this error:

```
    invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child 
(found: object with keys {description, id, links, name}). If you meant to render a 
collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using 
createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of 
`UserRow`.
```

Can someone please help me to fix it? Here is the parent component code:

```
export const UsersTable = React.createClass({
    getRoles(){
        var oneRole = "";
        this.props.users.forEach(function(user){
            server.getUserRoles(user.id,          
                (results) => {
                    this.oneRole =results['hits']['hits']
                    notifications.success("Get was successful ");
                },
                () => {
                    notifications.danger("get failed ");
                });  
            }.bind(this));
        return this.oneRole;
    },

    render() {
        var rows = [];
        var allroles = this.getRoles()
        this.props.users.map(function(user) {
            rows.push( <UserRow userID={user.id} 
                                userEmail={user.email} 
                                userRoles={allroles} 
                                roles={this.props.roles} />); 
            }.bind(this)); 
        return (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Email Address</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }    
});
```

And here is the child component code:

```
export const UserRow = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.userEmail}</td>
                <td>{this.props.userRoles}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: It is because the userRoles is an Object and you are trying to print it as a String. You will need to store it in a variable by looping through it and than you can just print that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the issue is when you render the userRoles. you need to loop over it and render an element for each role

```
export class UserRow extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.userEmail}</td>
                <td>{this.props.userRoles}</td>
--------------------^---------------------^
            </tr>
        );
    }
};
```

try this

```
export class UserRow extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const roles = this.props.userRoles.map((role) => <div>{role.id || ''}</div>);
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.userEmail}</td>
                <td>{roles}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Each object in `allroles` is a dictionary with these keys: description, id, links, name. So just need to edit your answer to get the correct value. instead of `{role}`, should be `{role['id']}`

Comment: @sarah awesome! glad that helped I updated my answer too :)